# Handle alert it doesn't in selenium 3 java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have a problem because I want to handle alert when I execute javascript. All is in selenium 3.0.1, JDK 1.8 and Firefox version 51.0.1.

My code:

```
public class SeleniumDemo {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\Damian6666\\Downloads\\geckodriver\\geckodriver.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://wikipedia.org");
        JavascriptExecutor jsx = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        jsx.executeScript("alert('Test Alerts');");    

        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
            alert.accept();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

In output I get:

```
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to find value field Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700' System info: host: 'Damian', ip: 'xxx.xxx.x.xxx', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_111' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver Capabilities [{rotatable=false, raisesAccessibilityExceptions=false, marionette=true, firefoxOptions={args=[], prefs={}}, appBuildId=20170125094131, version=, platform=XP, proxy={}, command_id=1, specificationLevel=0, acceptSslCerts=false, processId=6204, browserVersion=51.0.1, platformVersion=6.1, XULappId={ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, takesElementScreenshot=true, platformName=windows_nt}] Session ID: 912b309c-46a1-4b15-9f9e-f411a6905e87 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:127)  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:93) at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:42) at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:163) at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82) at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:537)
at selenium_demo.SeleniumDemo.main(SeleniumDemo.java:35) Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx1024m Java Result: 1 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 20 seconds)##
```

Comment: What are you using the `capabilities` object for?

Answer (score 1):

You should correctly instantiate driver via:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

It looks like you hit this bug: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/431

Answer (score 0):

Yes I forget about capabilities but when I add capabilities I get all time in output:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to find value field Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700' System info: host: 'Damian', ip: 'xxx.xxx.x.xx', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_111' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{rotatable=false, raisesAccessibilityExceptions=false, marionette=true, firefoxOptions={args=[], 
rofile=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}, appBuildId=20170125094131, version=, platform=XP, proxy={}, command_id=1, specificationLevel=0, acceptSslCerts=false, processId=8500, browserVersion=51.0.1, platformVersion=6.1, XULappId={ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, takesElementScreenshot=true, platformName=windows_nt}]
Session ID: bfebaee7-e2f8-430e-a4d6-368f2bc2a30f
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:127)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:93)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:42)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:163)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:537)
    at selenium_demo.Selenium_demo.main(Selenium_demo.java:38)
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx1024m
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 16 seconds)
```